# Langchain - Vector Store - Embeddings

Tags: langchain, openaiembeddings, vector-search

I have a chatbot, which basically does chat over document. there are multiple company information over which the chat has to be functioned.
each company information has to be segregated, mixing of information while retrieving should never happen. what is the right approach for segmentation of data or document while embedding documents using langchain (am using FAISS as vector database)